# What is Exactly AverageTimer32 in Performance monitoring background?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I read lots of articles, but i really confused about it.  it read that is background for calculating AverageTimer32 the system use this formula: `((N1 - N0) / F) / (B1 - B0)`

I searched about t this formula i find that:

> N1 current reading at time t (provided to the AverageTimer32/64)
>
> N0 reading before, at t – 1 (provided to the AverageTimer32/64)
>
> B1 current counter at t (provided to the AverageBase)
>
> B0 counter before, at t – 1 (provided to the AverageBase)
>
> F Factor to calculate ticks/seconds

the questions:

1-what `F` and HOW It was calculated? or where is it come from?

2-As the above was said `N0 reading before, at t – 1` , what is t-1 ? so if the current time is 01:14:44 how can i get t-1? it talk about second?

3- according to the this formula the AverageTime doesnot give a total average. for example if method A was called 4 times and its takes times in sec (in order): 2 sec , 4 sec, 3 sec , 2 sec, i assume it give us average times like this =>(2+4+3+2)/4 , and if the fifth called take 3 sec so : it give (2+4+3+2+3)/5, but it does not do like this?

and if its possible please explain more about about  AverageTimer32 formula.

thanks in adv